# Exception in invoking web Services with grails

Tags: web-services, grails

I am trying to use a external web service in my grails project following http://grails.org/Calling+External+WebServices

my wsdl - https://devora11.gryphon.priv/axis2/services/GDXAppWS?wsdl

Here's a simple code in controller where i am trying to use groovyx.net.ws.WSClient-:

```
    def proxy = new WSClient("https://devora11/axis2/services/GDXAppWS?wsdl", this.class.classLoader) 
            println "Proxy bfr "+proxy ; 
            //proxy.setSSLProperties(['port',':443']) 
            //println "Proxy "+proxy ; 
            print proxy.isSpecifiedSQLAlive()
```

but it throws error all the time- 
java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    at groovyx.net.ws.AbstractCXFWSClient.invokeMethod(AbstractCXFWSClient.java:87) 

    at com.ggw.LoadController$_closure2$$ENKIcufD.doCall(LoadController.groovy:41) 

    at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:26) 

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

On STS IDE shows
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] MyProj/load/wsTest 
Stacktrace follows: 
Message: null 
   Line | Method 
->>  87 | invokeMethod in groovyx.net.ws.AbstractCXFWSClient

---

|    41 | doCall       in com.ggw.LoadController$_closure2$$ENKIcufD 
|    26 | doFilter . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter 
|   886 | runTask      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
|   908 | run . . . .  in     '' 
^   662 | run          in java.lang.Thread

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have the URL for your web service wrong.

Comment: what looks wrong here ? If I past the url in browser, I can see the xml content with data. Looks to me the https issue.